# any suggestions to improve and bypass timeout error test with this prime finder function?

Tags: c, algorithm, performance, primes

I'm supposed to create a function to find the closest next prime number for a given number, I mean even though the algorithm is badly written and very slow (probably it's the slowest around), but its doing the task, the problem is the program supposed to evaluate my thing refuse it with timeout error, he had given it a bunch of numbers at once and he want them to be all resolved in 10 seconds, so the question is there any improvements you may suggest that could fast forward my poor tortue ? (`for` is not allowed)

```
int is_prime(int nb)
{
    int i;
    /* if negative terminate */
    if (nb <= 1)
        return (0);
    /* start from first prime */ 
    i = 2;
   /* primes equals zero only when divisible by 1 and theme-selves */
    while (nb % i != 0)
        i++;
    /* if i divides nb, we see if i is the nb we looking for */
    if (i == nb)
        return (1);
    else
        return (0);
}

int find_next_prime(int nb)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    /*keep looking for primes one by one */
    while (!is_prime(nb + i))
        i++;
    return (nb + i);
}
```

Comment: There are much faster method to compute that. Read carefully https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test.

Comment: `for` can be emulated with while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best simple speed improvement is to check divisors up to the square root of `n` rather than all divisors up to `n`.  This takes the algorithm from O(nb) to O(sqrt(nb)).

Consider `is_prime(2147483647)`.  OP's approach takes about 2147483647 iterations.  Testing up to about the square root, 46341, is about 46,000 times faster.

```
// while (nb % i != 0) i++;
// if (i == nb) return (1);
// else return (0);

// While the divisor <= quotient (or until the square root is reached)
while (i <= nb/i) {
  if (nb%i == 0) return 1;
  i++;
}
return 0;
```

---

Avoid a `i*i <= nb` test as `i*i` may overflow.
Avoid `sqrt(nb)` as than involves a host of floating point/`int` issues.
Note: Good compilers see nearby `nb/i; nb%i` and compute them both for the time cost of one.

Lots of other improvements are possible, but wanted to focus on a simple one with a big impact.  When wanting to improve speed focus on reducing order of complexity [O()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and not linear improvements.  [Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)

Answer (score 0):

Your missing the two most common tricks to improve speed.

- you only need to check up to square root of the number
- once you have check 2, you only need to check every other number from 3 on.

Comment: if you explain more detailed that would be great!

Comment: Also, after 2 and 3, all primes must be either `6n-1` or `6n+1`